# Can't install Mono on Mac

Tags: macos, mono, installation, osx-lion

I have tried many times to install Mono, using the current and beta builds. Every time I install it, it says that it's successful, but I go to the /Library/Frameworks folder and Mono just isn't there. I ran the uninstall script, but it said that permission was denied. I even tried turning on AppleShowAllFiles, and it still wasn't there. I am running OSX Lion.

-rulla101

Answer (score 1):

Check under /Users/_your_name_/Library/Frameworks

Regarding "permissions denied" try running the script with sudo command with terminal.